# Windows Phone App, triggering camera remotely

Tags: windows-phone-7.1, image

Trying to develop my first Windows Phone app, and I was wondering if there is a way to trigger the camera to take a picture remotely.

The research I have done on this has shown that it is impossible for an app to read a text message, so triggering via text seems to not be an option.

Is there any other way to make the camera take a picture? Or possibly could it be set up to take a picture upon receiving any text?

Answer (score 0):

Your app has to be running to open the camera.

Comment: Right. I am planning on leaving the app running, then remotely triggering the camera in some way. I was wondering if this was actually possible. Thanks.